# undefined variable on opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to get the order_id of each order on

```
catalog/controller/checkout/success.php

if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
    $this->cart->clear();

    //JACK - ADD ORDER ID TO NEW VARIABLE
    $order_id = $this->session->data['order_id'];
    //END MODIFICATION

    unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
    unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
    unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
    unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
    unset($this->session->data['guest']);
    unset($this->session->data['comment']);
    unset($this->session->data['order_id']);    
    unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
    unset($this->session->data['reward']);
    unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
    unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Undefined variable: order_id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php on line 121

        foreach($get_order_products as $prod){              

            $order_products[] = array(
                'order_id'  => $order_id
            );

        }
```

Comment: Right - as soon as you load that page, the `order_id` in the session is unset `unset($this->session->data['order_id']);` and the next time you load it, you have no `order_id` for your session. Loading this page with an active order will work just fine, but you need to ignore the code you're adding if its not set

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this,try this.

catalog/controller/checkout/success.php

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
    $this->cart->clear();

    //JACK - ADD ORDER ID TO NEW VARIABLE
    $order_id = $this->session->data['order_id'];
    //END MODIFICATION

    unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
    unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
    unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
    unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
    unset($this->session->data['guest']);
    unset($this->session->data['comment']);
    unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
    unset($this->session->data['reward']);
    unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
    unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);
}

 foreach($get_order_products as $prod){              

     $order_products[] = array(
        'order_id'  => $order_id
         );

 }

unset($this->session->data['order_id']);
```